# Symfony Routing: Can call route but not forward to

Tags: internationalization, url-routing, locale, symfony-2.1

I have a route for just the locale without any other information (the startpage that is):

```
homepage:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/
    defaults: { _controller: OurStartBundle:Default:index }
```

If I call the route directly it works (i.e.: localhost/de_DE/) but if I forward it throws the Error:

> Unable to parse the controller name "/app_dev.php/de_DE/".

I forward using the Controller Method like this:

```
$locale = \Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);    
return $this->forward($this->generateUrl('homepage', array('_locale' => $locale)));
```

Anyone jave any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that i used $this->forward() where i wanted a redirect and should have used $this->redirect().

Solution is:

```
$locale = \Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('OurStartBundle_homepage', array('_locale' => $locale)));
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to forward the request to a URI, rather than a bundle string.

For example, your forward call should be...

```
$response = $this->forward('OurStartBundle:Default:index', array(
    '_locale' => 'de_DE'
));
```

Comment: Ahh, no, not exactly what i wanted because i indeed wanted to change the Url. 
But i found my answer in your answer. I have to use $this->redirect($url) rather than $this->forward(..). Right.